# SQL query to verify account trade fee logic given data from another table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

I would like to verify a table `'account trade fee'` columns field are correctly recorded based on another table `'exchange trade'`.

Since I am really new to coding, would like to seek some help from yours.

Give background is now there is table `account trade fee`, as you see below there are column name `'fee_currency'`,`'maker_fee'` and `'taker_fee'`.

```
account_trade_fee

"account_uuid","fee_currency","maker_fee","taker_fee"
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa1,BTC,0.0002,0.0002
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa1,USDT,0.02,0.02
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa2,CRO,0.0002,0.0002
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa2,USDT,0.02,0.02
```

```
exchange_trade

"account_uuid","buy_fee_scale","buy_fee_value","buy_fee_currency","sell_fee_scale","sell_fee_value","sell_fee_currency","taker_side"
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa1,10,400000,BTC,8,400000,USDT,SELL
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa1,10,400000,BTC,8,400000,USDT,SELL
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa1,10,400000,BTC,8,400000,USDT,SELL
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa1,10,400000,BTC,8,400000,USDT,SELL
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa1,10,400000,BTC,8,400000,USDT,SELL
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa1,10,400000,BTC,8,400000,USDT,BUY
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa1,10,400000,BTC,8,400000,USDT,BUY
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa1,10,400000,BTC,8,400000,USDT,BUY
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa1,10,400000,BTC,8,400000,USDT,BUY
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa1,10,400000,BTC,8,400000,USDT,BUY
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa2,10,400000,CRO,8,400000,USDT,SELL
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa2,10,400000,CRO,8,400000,USDT,SELL
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa2,10,400000,CRO,8,400000,USDT,SELL
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa2,10,400000,CRO,8,400000,USDT,SELL
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa2,10,400000,CRO,8,400000,USDT,SELL
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa2,10,400000,CRO,8,400000,USDT,BUY
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa2,10,400000,CRO,8,400000,USDT,BUY
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa2,10,400000,CRO,8,400000,USDT,BUY
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa2,10,400000,CRO,8,400000,USDT,BUY
c3f94bdf-8854-49d2-833d-0690eb821aa2,10,400000,CRO,8,400000,USDT,BUY
```

There is equation of calculating the maker fee and taker fee from exchange trade table.
If from below column 'taker_side':

if taker_side = 'BUY' refers to a maker fee, BTC would be the buy_fee_currency.
which the formula would be `buy_fee_value/pow(10,buy_fee_scale) = 0.00004`.
Since there is total five trade from BTC_USDT pair are BUY side.
So the final maker fee would be `0.00004 * 5 = 0.0002` for BTC currency, which shows the same result from account trade fee above.

As BTC would be the `buy_fee_currency`, then USDT would be the `sell_fee_curreny` so then it will calculated as taker_fee and formula is like
`sell_fee_value/pow(10,sell_fee_scale) = 0.004` . Since there are total five trade are "SELL" side, times 5 would equal to `0.004 * 5 = 0.02`

vice versa to the case if taker_side is "SELL"
BTC is sell_fee_currency.
USDT is buy_fee_currency.

I could only manage to write some sql query like below , but it couldn't generate the expected sum as I don't know how to control the calculation with regard to maker side or buyer side.In order to verify if the logic apply correctly, I would like to write a query to check if the sum of each currency is correctly display in maker_fee and taker_fee. Could any one kindly advise how to do so?

```
select account_uuid , taker_side
case 
    when taker_side = 'BUY' 
    then (
    sum((buy_fee_value/power(10,buy_fee_scale)) as maker_fee,
    select buy_fee_currency as fee_currecny )
    end
case 
    when taker_side = 'SELL' 
    then (
    sum((sell_fee_value/power(10,sell_fee_scale)) as taker_fee,
    select sell_fee_currency as fee_currecny    )
    end
from exchange_trade et 
group by account_uuid ,taker_side
```

Comment: I am sorry that I missed out to put my code out there, have added back the code.

Comment: There are lots of syntax problems with that query, not just logic problems.

Comment: 1. You can't put multiple expressions in the `THEN` clause of `CASE`. 2. `AS maker_fee` has to go after the `END`. 3. you're missing commas between the columns in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: It should be `SUM(CASE ...)` not `CASE ... THEN SUM(...)`

Comment: Thanks @Barmar

I am now able to query the result with below command.

`select distinct account_uuid,
taker_side,
sum(case 
 when taker_side = 'BUY' then ((buy_fee_value/power(10,buy_fee_scale)))
 end) as maker_fee,
sum(case
 when taker_side = 'SELL'then ((sell_fee_value/power(10,sell_fee_scale)))
 end) as taker_fee   
from
exchange_trade et
group by
account_uuid,taker_side
order by account_uuid `